# Send data from android app to pc app through usb cable

Tags: android, usb

> Hello everyone! I want to design an simple app that sends some data such as integer, string,... to an pc application through usb cable. So, how to do that?

Comment: Search for `USB serial` with additional keywords on both sides of the wire.

Comment: @MorrisonChang  thanks for your help. Let me try it